# c# xml serialization with XmlAttribute tag

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object using XmlSerializer. The input class that has a property with [XmlAttribute] is not showing up in output xml. Anyway to fix this?

Comment: can you please post your code!

Comment: Can we see the class please? Context is everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it not to appear at all, one of these things is usually true:

- the type is not appropriately accessible; for typical values, this means that it needs a `public` getter and setter; if it lacks both: *it will not be serialized* (note that for collections, only a getter is required)
- conditional serialization of some form is enabled (either via `[DefaultValue]`, or a `ShouldSerialize*()` method), and is indicating to omit it
- it is being fully ignored (`[XmlIgnore]`, for example)